# How to find the value of particular row in gridview?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

How can i find value of particular row in gridview. Say a gridview has 10 rows and 4 columns. I know that we can find the row number from row index, but how can we find what is the value of column 2 of row 5 (as per my gridview) or know a value of the cell?

Comment: posting your GridView's markup and the associated events code would help us in helping you resolve the issues you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
CustomersGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Text
```

More about [.Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows.aspx) collection

If you are interested in `FindControl` method, the most suitable event for you is [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx):

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var control = e.Row.Cell[cellIndex].FindControl("ControlID");
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = ((TypeOfControl)control).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: what needs to be given in cellIndex?

Comment: @Xor power You must cast your control to the needed type. Updated the Answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming one cell per column this should do the trick:

```
string cellValue = GridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text;
```

That would give you the value of column 2 at row 5.

Depending on how the row is built (if, for example, one column has a DropDownList or some other such control) you might be better off doing `FindControl(controlID)`.

**UPDATE**

Say you have a `DropDownList` in the 2nd column with ID="ddlMyDropDown":

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[4].FindControl("ddlMyDropDown");
```

Which event to put the code in depends on why you're trying to find the value.  If you can give an example of when/why you'd need to get the value, we can tell you which event it should probably go in.

**UPDATE 2**

Assuming there's a button in the row, handle the `RowCommand` event:

```
protected void GridVie1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddlMyDropDown");

    // Do something
}
```

Do be cautious here, however, as the RowCommand is fired whenever a button in the row is clicked, so you'd need to make sure which button was clicked.  You could use `e.CommandName` to get the CommandName of the button if you set it, but be aware that there are some predefined names.

See [GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) for more information.

If you can update your question with some more information (i.e., why you need to get the value and what interaction with the GridView would start that process, like a button click) a more precise answer can be provided.

I'm about done for the night, but I'll check back on this thread tomorrow.

Comment: How to do with FindControl? Plus, where to put the code, i mean which event?

Comment: from above example(ddl), i am not getting which row user has clicked. I cannot give as command argument as i have alerady provided ID (primary key column) as command argument. Hence either i need to know which row is clicked or else if i am giving row index as command argument, i need to know the value of ID (primary key column)

Comment: By row clicked, if you mean a button in the row was clicked, you could handle the RowCommand event.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Yes.. something like that... either i need to know the which row was clicked or the value of ID..

Comment: thanks!. but rowcommand event is not being fired up? I h've binded with gridview still..

Answer (score 2):

If you know the value of a cell then we can find the row

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Contains("sometext"))
        {
            //code here..
        }
    }
}
```